# There's something wrong in my Magic Square Algorithm

Tags: java, magic-square

Hi I created a Magic Square program in java
It works fine if you input a number 3 but if i input 5 and so on 
there's a problem occurring.. 
The pattern becomes wrong.

Please help me to find out what's wrong in my code:

Here's my code:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int num = input.nextInt();

    // Number must be ODD and not less than or equals to one to continue
    while ((num % 2 == 0) || (num <= 1)) {
        System.out.println("Enter a valid number: ");
        num = input.nextInt();
    }

    int[][] magic = new int[num][num];

    int row = 0;
    int col = num / 2;
    magic[row][col] = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= num * num; i++) {
        if (magic[(row + 5) % num][(col + 2) % num] == 0) {
            row = (row + 5) % num;
            col = (col + 2) % num;
        } else {
            row = (row + 1 + num) % num;
        }
        magic[row][col] = i;
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < num; x++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            System.out.print(magic[x][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

It's correct when i Input 3,
here's the output:

[image]

But when i type a number like 5:
It becomes:

[image]

UPDATED!

Comment: Please add what you want to accomplish with your algorithm

Comment: Please explain how it is failing.

Comment: sorry for incomplete information.
So i edited and now this is my new question

Comment: Please explain the purpose of the constants +5 and +2.

Comment: Why move row + 5 and col + 2? move both +1 and if the value is 0 move to the previous row and same col.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to implement the [Method for constructing a magic square of odd order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square#Method_for_constructing_a_magic_square_of_odd_order).

> The method prescribes starting in the central column of the first row with the number 1.

You seem to have that right.

> After that, the fundamental movement for filling the squares is diagonally up and right, one step at a time.

I would code this as:

```
int newRow = row - 1;
int newCol = col + 1;
```

> When an "up and to the right" move would leave the square, it is wrapped around to the last row or first column, respectively.

This is clearly:

```
if ( newRow < 0 ) {
  newRow = num - 1;
}
if ( newCol > num - 1 ) {
  newCol = 0;
}
```

> If a filled square is encountered, one moves vertically down one square instead, then continues as before.

```
if (magic[newRow][newCol] != 0) {
  newRow = row + 1;
  newCol = col;
}
```

I know this doesn't actually solve your problem but I hope it gets you somewhere towards your goal. See how I take the words of the algorithm and match them as accurately as possible with code.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question
I would try to test this but is there a way that i could just edit my work because i think there's something wrong in my loop, i think my formula was wrong, i need a new formula for that

Comment: @repsajznav  The code I posted would be a good replacement of what you have in your loop